# No visible @interface for UITableView when deleting a row

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios5, delete-row

I know this type of questions has been asked here on SO before and I've tried almost all of them but to no avail. I'm trying to delete a row from a UITableView. Here is my code.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        //calls to a method that deletes the row from the backend SQLite database
        [self deleteCompany:indexPath.row];

        //theCompanies is a NSMutableArray. When the app starts, it retrieves the data and display it in the UITableView
        [theCompanies removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        //Below line is where the error occurs. 
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                         withRowAnimation:YES
              UITableViewRowAnimationFade:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {

    }   
}
```

I get the following complier error when I build the app.

*No visible @interface for 'UITableView' declares the selector...*

I hav no clue what I should do next. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the next part of the error message. You left out the important part :-)

Comment: Why don't you read the documentation by the way? Also, this is way too basic - you don't even know the correct syntax for calling a method.

Comment: @H2CO3 I assume you're the downvoter. Maybe its way too basic for you. But I just started iOS development only a couple of weeks ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method is like this

```
- (void)deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
```

With two argument see here [Apple UITableView Document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/deleteRowsAtIndexPaths%3awithRowAnimation%3a)

But you have used like is is of three argument and withRowAnimation as BOOL but it is not BOOL.

Try something like this:

```
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

Answer (score 2):

Change this line:

```
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                         withRowAnimation:YES
              UITableViewRowAnimationFade:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

to

```
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                         withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```